# Orthonormal set and Fourier Series

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-series

I'm trying to workout an example of a textbook on undergrad functional analysis I'm studying but something's just not working out. Probably missing on something really basic. I'm gonna state some results first:

> **Proposition:** Let $\mathscr{S}=\{e_i:i\in \mathbb{N}\}$ be an orthonormal set in an inner product space $E$. If $u=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \xi _ie_i$, then $u_i=\langle u,e_i\rangle =\xi _i$ and $\|u\|^2=\sum_{i=1}^\infty |\xi _i|^2$, where $u_i$ is the Fourier coefficient of $u$ in the $e_i$ direction.

> **Theorem (Riesz-Fischer):** Let $\mathscr{S}=\{e_i:i\in \mathbb{N}\}$ be an orthonormal set in a Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$. Given a sequence $(\xi _i)\in \mathbb{K}$, the series $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \xi _ie_i$ converges if and only if the series $\sum_{i=1}^\infty |\xi _i|^2$ converges.

So now we get an orthonormal system$$\mathscr{S}=\left \{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}},\frac{\cos t}{\sqrt{\pi}}, \frac{\sin t}{\sqrt{\pi}},\frac{\cos 2t}{\sqrt{\pi}},\frac{\sin 2t}{\sqrt{\pi}},\ldots \right \}$$on the Hilbert space $L^2([-\pi ,\pi ],\mathbb{R})$. Choose constants $a_0,a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2,\ldots$ such that$$\frac{a_0^2}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left (a_k^2+b_k^2\right )<\infty .$$Now, the textbook says that by the Riesz-Fischer Theorem there exists $f\in L^2([-\pi ,\pi ],\mathbb{R})$ given by$$f=a_0\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left (a_k\frac{\cos kt}{\sqrt{\pi}}+b_k\frac{\sin kt}{\sqrt{\pi}}\right ).$$I think this should be pretty obvious and direct but I'm getting a different answer. Since $\xi _0^2=|\xi _0|^2=\frac{a_0^2}{2}$, I'm getting this:$$f=a_0\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left (a_k\frac{\cos kt}{\sqrt{\pi}}+b_k \frac{\sin kt}{\sqrt{\pi}}\right ).$$Later, in another example, they refer to $\mathscr{S}$ saying that it forms an orthonormal basis for $L^2([-\pi ,\pi],\mathbb{R})$ and says that every function $f$ in this space can be written by$$f(t)=\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\cos nt+b_n\sin nt.$$What is happening? Shouldn't it be the same as earlier? Is the textbook wrong or am I going crazy?

In both examples they state that$$a_k=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t)\cos kt\,dt,\quad k\in \{0,1,2,\ldots \}$$and$$b_k=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t)\sin kt\,dt,\quad k\in \mathbb{N},$$which made sense to me.

I haven't found another reference that makes a similar treatment on the subject, if you guys have any recommendations it'd be great! Thanks in advance!

Comment: As long as you don't specify what your constants $a_k$ are, e.g. Fourier coefficients, they can be anything. All three statements are correct, but each time the $a_k$ are different constants.

Comment: They state that the $a_k$ is the same for both cases. I'm gonna edit, sorry

Comment: Maybe there are some typos. The last definition of $f(t)$ is consistent with formula (6), but the definitions of $a_k$ and $b_k$ are inconsistent with formulas (7) to (9) at https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeries.html.

Comment: @StevenClark couldn't this be because they're using a different orthonormal set on $L^2([-\pi, \pi], \mathbb{R})$  to calculate the coefficients?

Comment: The definitions of $a_k$ and $b_k$ here are different by a factor of $\sqrt{\pi}$, so plugging them into the same formula for $f(t)$ will lead to a difference of a factor of $\sqrt{\pi}$ in $f(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

The constants are basically irrelevant. But the easiest convention is the one where the resulting basis is orthonormal, which is
$$
      \left\{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}},\frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{\pi}},\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{\pi}},\frac{\cos(2x)}{\sqrt{\pi}},\frac{\sin(2x)}{\sqrt{\pi}},\cdots\cdots \right\}.
$$
This is the correct normalization for an orthonormal basis of $L^2[0,2\pi]$, which is undoubtedly why they are using their normalization. Then the ordinary Fourier series for $f\in L^2[0,2\pi]$ is an expansion along an orthonormal basis of $L^2[0,\pi]$:
$$
        f=\langle f,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\rangle\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}+\langle f,\frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{\pi}}\rangle\frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{\pi}}+\langle f,\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{\pi}}\rangle\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{\pi}}+\cdots \\
   = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(x')dx'+\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(x')\cos(x')dx'\cos(x)+\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(x')\sin(x')dx'\sin(x)+\cdots.
$$